# Entity Framework: Update entity with relationship to collection of objects of same type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to know if the following is possible with fewer database calls.

I have a model where I need to go back and save other entities of the same type to itself (obviously avoiding circular referencing).

```
public class OneItemOfTheModel
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "PK Id")]
    public int OneItemOfTheModelPK{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Listing ID")]
    public int ListingID{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cool Property name")]
    public string CoolProp{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Related Models")]
    public virtual ICollection<OneItemOfTheModel> RelatedModels { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parent Object Thing")]
    public virtual ParentObjectThing ParentObj { get; set; }
 }
```

Data is imported from rows of a csv file. Initially a "Parent Object Thing" will be created, a new model entity created and linked to that parent and fields populated with the row in the csv:

```
 ListingID/CoolProp
 1, "whoa"
 2, "awesome"
 3, "data"
 4, "awesome"
 5, "awesome"
```

The desired result is to end up with the following where entities with the same "Cool Property" are linked in the database:

```
 PK/ListingID/CoolProp/RelatedModels/ParentObj
 5083,1,"whoa",,53
 5084,2,"awesome",[5086,5087],53
 5085,3,"data",,53
 5086,4,"awesome",[5084,5087],53
 5087,5,"awesome",[5084,5086],53
```

Currently I am saving entities to the database first and then running another followup method to link individual entities together.

```
 public void SyncRelatedProperties (int parentObjID, efContext db )
    {
        List<OneItemOfTheModel> myItemList = db.OneItemOfTheModel.Where(b => b.ParentObjID == ParentObjID && b.CoolProp.Length > 0).ToList();
        if (myItemList.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach( OneItemOfTheModel t in myItemList)
            {
                List<OneItemOfTheModel> tmplist = db.OneItemOfTheModel.Where(b => b.CoolProp == t.CoolProp && b.ListingID != t.ListingID).ToList();
                foreach ( OneItemOfTheModel b in tmplist)
                {
                    t.RelatedModels.Add(b);
                }
            }
        db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Obviously this doesn't scale very well when users are importing files with hundreds of lines with tens of related properties to map.

I've played around a bit with "GroupBy" on CoolProp and clearing out the self referencing ListingID but I'm not confident enough with my knowledge of EF to know at what stage I'll be referencing a shallow copy instead of the original entity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just adding all the Entities and calling .SaveChanges()?  EF will attempt a [Topological Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the entities so that they are inserted in an order that is consistent with the foreign key dependencies.